# Django in Apache via mod_fcgid: How to track down FastCGI errors?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-fcgid

Due to a series of legacy infra-struture I have to deploy a Django application in an Apache server via `mod_fcgid` (no nginx, no `mod_wsgi` neither `mod_uswgi`).

I followed [Django (1.8) instructions to deploy via FastCGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#running-django-on-a-shared-hosting-provider-with-apache) but `mod_fcgid` is exiting and I don't why.

The most useful piece of information I get is `exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 120`. No idea what might be raising that.

---

Here is Apache's `error_log`:

```
[Tue Feb 16 13:20:28 2016] [info] mod_fcgid: server subdomain.domain.com:/path/to/project/index.fcgi(15473) started
[Tue Feb 16 13:20:31 2016] [info] mod_fcgid: process /path/to/project/index.fcgi(15473) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 120
```

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And this is my `index.fcgi`:

```
#!/path/to/project/venv/bin/python

import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/project")
os.chdir("/path/to/project")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

I tried with and without the `sys.path(…)` and `os.chdir(…)` lines and some other minor changes such as using `/path/to/project` (where `manage.py` is) or `/path/to/project/project` (the package itself).

Comment: Wrap a try except around the runfastcgi call and implement some logging

Comment: @Rel Sorry about my delay. Thanks for your idea, gonna try it and update here soon.